# How to specify the target directory for bower-install?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower

In my `index.html` file, I've added that:

```
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- endbower -->
```

in order to let `install-bower` grunt task to put all my Bower dependencies. In my `Gruntfile.js`, I have the following task:

```
    'bower-install': {
        dist: {
            html: 'cwf/index.html'
        }
    }
```

At the end, in my `index.html`, I get something like:

```
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    ...
    <!-- endbower -->
```

However, I want to configure the task to prepend `../` before the `bower_components`, so to get that:

```
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    ...
    <!-- endbower -->
```

How can I configure the task for that purpose?

Comment: As you did not accept the answerr below, am I right in assuming that you haven't found a statisfying solution to the issue yet?

Comment: That's perfectly right, @user2422960

Answer (score 5):

create a file named: `.bowerrc` within the where your bower.json is located at.
That's how you can configure your bower.

Add the property `directory`, to specify the download path for the components.

Content of the .bowerrc

```
{
  "directory": "../yourCustomPath/"
}
```

Comment: This configuration will *also* move the `bower_components` outside my project (at the parent dir.). I don't want that in fact. I really prefer to configure the `bower-install` Grunt task instead of Bower itself...

Comment: then make it "./components" or something. The property is a folder path "../" make it point to parent.

Comment: Why is this not possible from bower.json ??